# Deleting rows and columns from matrix in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

My task is to delete identical rows and columns from matrix without deleting the first identical row/column. For example, if second, third, and fourth row are identical, third and fourth row should be deleted and second row should be kept. The same goes for columns. I tried to solve this task, but, I have some mistake in my code, and I don't know if my approach is correct. I hope that you could help me.

```c
#if 0
Sample Input:
1 2 1 2 3
1 2 1 2 3
1 2 1 2 3
   
Sample Output:
1 2 3
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int M, N, m[100][100], i, j, a = 0, k, b = 0;

    printf("Enter dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if(m[i][j] != m[a][j])
            {
                a++;
                continue;
            }

            if(m[i][j] != m[b][j])
            {
                b++;
                continue;
            }

            if(i == M)
            {
                for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
                {
                    m[i][k] = m[i][k + 1];
                }
                N--;
            }

        }
        if(j == N)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                m[i][k] = m[i + 1][k];
            }
            M--;
        }

    }

    printf("New matrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide an input for testing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "deleting"? Do you mean replacing values with zeroes? What would be helpful for anyone trying to answer is a sample input with the expected output for the sample input.

Comment: @asuka I have included the example

Comment: @Tom I thought since in the example the 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows are identical, the 2nd and 3rd rows should be removed, and then the output will be `1 2 1 2 3` - why does it go to `1 2 3`?

Comment: @asuka Because the same rule applies to columns, too

Comment: @ShaneBishop I have included the example

Comment: @Tom I am still confused, if the rule applies to rows and columns at the same time, since all of the 5 columns are same, they should all be erased, and the output becomes empty.

Comment: @asuka The first identical row/column should be kept; it should not be deleted

Comment: still can't get it - it is too hard for me, see if any others can help

Comment: @asuka if two or more rows or columns are identical all except the first identical row/column should be deleted. For example, if you have matrix 2x3 with first row 1 2 3 and second row 1 2 3 the output should be 1 2 3 since the first identical row should not be deleted

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a function that takes in the base pointer of arrays A and B and returns true if they are identical. For eg.

`bool are_identical(int* A, int* B, int len); // true if A[i] = B[i], for all 0 <= i < len`

I am assuming that there is a good number of deletions, so a better choice will be to have an array of pointers to pointers (which points to the base ptr of each row) than to have a 2D array. Because deletions are fairly simple as you just need to free(deallocate) a certain row and shift the base ptr by one place starting from the current place. This is of O(row) worst time complexity.

```cpp
int** array_of_base_ptr;

// generate k new rows

for(int i=0; i < k; i++) {
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(SIZE_OF_ARRAY * sizeof(int));
    array_of_base_ptr[k] = arr;
}
 
/*
 SOME OTHER CODE
*/


if (are_identical(array_of_base_ptr[i], array_of_base_ptr[j], SIZE_OF_ARRAY)) {
   free(array_of_base_ptr[j]); // j = i + 1

   /* 
      followed by code to shift everything one row back 

      something like this:

      array_of_base_ptr[j] = array_of_base_ptr[j+1]; for all j > i

   */

}
```

But if you have really a lot of deletions, it is better to have a linked list kind of data structure (to store the base ptr of each row) where deletions are O(1), as you just need to delete a single node.

Comment: Using functions to find common elements is not permitted

Comment: Doesn't matter, I tried to make code modular, you can put that function's code within the main() function or better to use lambda functions of c++.